# Jquery fortune wheel getting wrong result

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I am creating a fortune wheel using jquery and want to getting the exact number from the spinning wheel

Jquery I am using this in html

```
var prices = [{
  name: '0'
}, {
  name: '1'
}, {
  name: '2'
}, {
  name: '3'
}, {
  name: '4'
}, {
  name: '5'
}, {
  name: '6'
}, {
  name: '7'
}, {
  name: '8'
}, {
  name: '9'
}, {
  name: '10'
}, {
  name: '11'
}, {
  name: '12'
}, {
  name: '13'
}, {
  name: '14'
}, {
  name: '15'
}, {
  name: '16'
}, {
  name: '17'
}, {
  name: '18'
}, {
  name: '19'
}, {
  name: '20'
}, {
  name: '21'
}, {
  name: '22'
}, {
  name: '23'
}, {
  name: '24'
}, {
  name: '25'
}, {
  name: '26'
}, {
  name: '27'
}, {
  name: '28'
}, {
  name: '29'
}, {
  name: '31'
}, {
  name: '32'
}, {
  name: '33'
}, {
  name: '34'
}, {
  name: '35'
}, {
  name: '36'
}];

$(function() {
  var $r = $('.roulette').fortune(prices);

  var clickHandler = function() {
    $('.spinner').off('click');
    $('.spinner span').hide();
    $r.spin().done(function(price) {
      $('.price').text('You have: ' + price.name);
      $('.spinner').on('click', clickHandler);
      $('.spinner span').show();
    });
  };

  $('.spinner').on('click', clickHandler);
});
```

I am not sure where I am going with this code. everytime its spin its give me incorrect result.Please May be I am confuse with the logic behind this spinning wheel. Please help me with this

Here is the live example of what i created so far. Please guide me what I have to do to get the accurate result

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWwVVj

Comment: do you mean your getting the wrong result because the white ball is not on the number it selects?

Comment: The problem is because your `prices` array is in numerical order. It should be in the same order as the values in shown on the roulette wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because your `prices` array is in numerical order. It should be in the same order as the values in shown on the roulette wheel, like this:

```
var prices = [
  { name: 0 }, 
  { name: 26 }, 
  { name: 3 }
  // ...
];
```

[**Updated Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gWwPWN)

Also note that your array of objects with just one property is pretty redundant. You can just use an array of integers instead, like this:

```
var prices = [0, 26, 3, 35, 12, 28, 7, 29, 18, 22, 9, 31, 14, 20, 1, 33, 16, 24, 5, 10, 23, 8, 30, 11, 36, 13, 27, 6, 34, 17, 25, 2, 21, 4, 19, 15, 32];
```

[**Updated Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WjGrEr)

Comment: Thanks Man it is awesome.. You save my day :)